# SQL: Group data without using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, group-by, grouping, searchkick

Hello fellow engineers!

I have encountered an interesting task to which I have so far not found a solution.
Maybe a Collective Mind will be able to solve it? :)

So, we've got three bookstores, they sell books.
One sells them well and generates an income of 3 coins per book.
Second one - two coins.
Third one is the worst, one coin.

We also have books. Lots of books. They can be sold in any of the bookstores in any combination.
When a visitor comes in and asks for a list of books, we want to list all the books, but send him to the most paying bookstore for that book, of course.
So if a good book is available in all three stores, we want to show that it's available in store #1.

Now, at this point I think it calls for a structure description...

Let's assume following DB structure:

```
create table books      ( id serial primary key, name text, bookstore_id int );
create table bookstores ( id serial primary key, name text, cost_per_book int );

insert into bookstores (id, name, cost_per_book) values
(1, 'Good', 1),
(2, 'Bad',  2),
(3, 'Ugly', 3);

insert into books (name, bookstore_id) values
('a good book',     1),
('a good book',     3),
('a good book',     2),
('an average book', 3),
('an average book', 2),
('an OK book',      3),
('an OK book',      2),
('last book',       3);
```

When doing a query for the list books, we want to see a following list:

```
 name             | bookstore_id 
------------------+-------------
'a good book',    | 1
'an average book',| 2
'an OK book',     | 2
'last book',      | 3
```

Now, for what makes this task seemingly impossible: no GROUPing or aggregation (nor DISTINCT) should be used in the query. Yeah, that's the trick...

It is, however, allowed to extend and expand table structure and data set in any way that might help in achieving the result.

**The resulting query should consist only of `where` conditions, however crazy those may be.**

And be run in a reasonable time, of course.

I've spent quite a number of hours trying to solve this riddle... Is it even possible though?

Oh, and here's a link to the SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4ea57

UPD. A bit more context to the story... The resulting query should be possible to translate into a set of "where" conditions for ElasticSearch using a `searchkick` gem. While ES can perform aggregations, it is still very tricky and awkward to do so while retaining proper pagination, so the "best" approach is assumed to be one with no aggregations used. And this is what I'm trying to come up with...

Sorry for the mishaps.

Answer (score 1):

You could use exists logic here:

```sql
SELECT name, bookstore_id
FROM books b1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM books b2
    WHERE b2.name = b1.name AND
          b2.bookstore_id < b1.bookstore_id
);
```

Comment: Ah, almost, but not quite - distinct is still a form of an aggregation. Alas, can not be used.

Comment: `distinct is still a form of an aggregation` ... no it's not.  I will add a `ROW_NUMBER` option instead (which you _shouldn't_ use, you should use `DISTINCT ON` which will perform better).

Comment: OK, this calls for more context... The resulting query should be possible to translate into a set of "where" conditions for ElasticSearch. While ES can perform aggregations, it is still very tricky and awkward to do so while retaining proper pagination. :/

Comment: Answer updated.  It helps to put the requirements into the actual question before posting.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, my apologies, question updated accordingly.